# undefined behavior when passing argument in C++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, undefined-behavior

Is there a order which is followed when passing argument to a function in c++? or is it compiler dependent?
I am unable to understand the output what is happening here?!

```
#include <iostream>

void sum(int a, int b){
  std::cout << "a = " << a << " " << "b = " << b << '\n';
  std::cout << "sum = " << a+b;
  
}
int main(){
  int a=1;
  sum(++a, a++);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a = 3
b = 1
sum = 4
```

Regards

Comment: If you know it's UB, what exactly are you trying to understand about the output?

Comment: I wanted to know a little bit about the working as it is surely not providing random values. In this case a is always incremented by 2 and b remains the same as in the main function. Actually I don't really know what UB means, it does not seem that much "undefined", I checked few online compilers also they all provide same output so how is this UB(I am guessing from the dictionary meaning)

Comment: Actually UB means you can't make *any* claims about what a program will do across different compilers. You *can* ask what it will do for a specific compiler, on a specific architecture, with specific flags, etc. but that's a different question.

Comment: I am getting same output in online compilers as well are are they all  MinGW which I am using?

Comment: Not at all. Again, UB means anything can happen, and I do mean anything. For example, all compilers might produce the same result for a program with UB.

Comment: Oh! right that sure is a possibility.     Thank You for your time.